# Solving the limit as it goes to 0 without using sympy?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a homework problem to "Find the lim as x->0 for the equation ((1-x)^3 -1 + 3x) / x^2). Then do it for very small values of x (like x = 10^-10) and see if anything happens. Then it says find a way to evaluate the expression more accurately. The issue is, if you plug 0 into the equation, you will obviously get "cannot divide by 0". I also have an un-simplifyable equation to solve:

> lim x->0 (e^x - x - 1) / x^2

I am 99% sure we cannot use sympy because we won't be "learning the process" of the problem itself. From what I understand, there should be a way I can simplify the numerator and denominator (possibly using matrices?).

I do not need someone to do the problem for me, but does anyone have a suggestion to point me in the right direction?

Comment: This looks like a calculus problem, not a programming problem. You may want to look into things like L'Hospital's Rule rather than plugging anything into sympy. Keep in mind that sympy only works if you understand what it does. It's important to learn the fundamentals first.

Comment: If you solve this equation `lim x->0 {((1-x)^3 -1 + 3x) / x^2)}`, it reduces to lim x->0 {(3-x)}